# Is the function $f:[0, \infty) \rightarrow (-\infty,\frac{9}{4}], f(x)=-x^{2}+x+2$ surjective, injective or both?

Tags: calculus, functions

Is the function $f:[0, \infty) \rightarrow (-\infty,\frac{9}{4}], f(x)=-x^{2}+x+2$ surjective, injective or both?

I think it isn't an injection because it doesn't pass the horizontal line test and it's a surjection because for every $y\in(-\infty, \frac{9}{4}]$ we can find it's original in $[0,\infty)$.

I'm not sure whether this is correct, and I'm also wondering how would you **prove** this function is surjective and not injective. I assume you can't just say look at the graph.

Comment: but $f(0)=f(1)$.

Comment: Yes, I found a typo in my calculations. So it's not an injection. I'll edit my post. Would that be a proof it's not injective? How would you prove it's a surjection?

Comment: To prove that it is surjective, just solve the equation $-x^2+x+2=y$ for a given $y \in (-\infty,9/4]$.

Comment: @Now_now_Draco_play_nicely two points with the same value directly implies non injective; for another side just notice that $-x^2+x+a$ has a nonnegative root when $a\ge -\frac{1}{4}$; to do this you can complete the square and write $x$ in term of $a$ explicitly.